# Getting 'missing prvCreatemsdyn_quotepricelist privilege' error in creating quote in Dynamics-365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

When I am trying to create a brand new **Quote** in Dynamics-365(version 9.1), I am getting this error.

**Message:**

> Principal user (Id=a8103c68-a82d-e811-b955-000d3p1aba11, type=8, roleCount=6, privilegeCount=1021, accessMode=0, is missing prvCreatemsdyn_quotepricelist privilege (Id=3312531a-a75f-4aa9-855c-53e23f5c0b6e) on OTC=10082

The security role given to this user is:
1. Customer Service app access
2. Project Service Automation app access
3. Sales app access
4. Sales Manager
5. Sales Support Representative
6. Sales Person

I though these privileges would be enough to create a brand new quote in my environment. But I am not being able to create.

Which privileges should I have to create a brand new Quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error details prvCreatemsdyn_quotepricelist,
It clearly states that you do not have create rights on quote price list entity.
You need to provide create rights and then shall work.